# Reading Text file C#

Tags: c#

I have the following text contents (save in a .txt file)

```
  Region2    Region3     Region4   Region5   Region6 
Mod Fwd   Dir     TOP SYS  SECURITY    ZONING      BOTTOM    FCC DIS   FCC ENA 
    Eng          Use/Total Use/Total  Use/Total   Use/Total Use/Total Use/Total
--- ---  ------ ---------- --------- ------------ --------- --------- ---------
1   1    INPUT     20/407     1/407      0/2852      8/407     0/0       0/0   
1   1    OUTPUT     0/25      0/25       0/140       0/25      0/12      1/25  
1   2    INPUT     20/407     1/407      0/2852      8/407     0/0       0/0   
1   2    OUTPUT     0/25      0/25       0/140       0/25      0/12      1/25  
1   3    INPUT     20/407     1/407      0/2852      4/407     0/0       0/0   
1   3    OUTPUT     0/25      0/25       0/140       0/25      0/12      1/25
```

What I Need to get is the zoning details only and put that in another text file so the end result should look like this

```
Region3 - Zoning
Use/Total
0/2852
0/140
0/2852
0/140
0/2852
0/140
```

I am struggling to read the format correctly any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's separator is used? tabs or spaces?

Comment: You can look at `System.IO.Stream` and `string.Split`. They will help you.

Comment: Converting the file to a `csv` would save you a world of hurt. You wouldn't even need C# - just Excel.

Comment: instead of stating that you are struggling to read the format correctly.. please show us what you have thus far so that we can see where you are going wrong. also post an actual single line example of what the contents are in the textfile. this is actually not that difficult to do

Comment: This looks like it is a fixed field length file, in that case the data will start on the same position in each line. You can use the String's Substring method to get it. Try position 38 with a length of 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so a new day and a fresh mind, thanks for all your comments.  This is how I resolved the issue (the thing here is that it will take into account if the zoning column moves to a different location)

Here is the code

```
int headerCount = 1;
        int zoneNumber = 0;
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\tcam\test.txt");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            headerCount++;
            if (headerCount == 6)
            {
                string[] zonelocation = line.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                int zoneCount = 0;
                string lastVal = "";
                foreach (var x in zonelocation)
                {
                    zoneCount++;
                    if (lastVal.ToLower() == "top" && x.ToLower() == "sys") zoneCount--;
                    if (x.ToLower() == "zoning") zoneNumber = zoneCount - 1;
                    lastVal = x;
                }
            }
            if (headerCount > 8)
            {
                string[] zoneinfo = line.Split(new char[0], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                if (zoneinfo.Any())
                {
                    string[] zoneData = zoneinfo[zoneNumber].Split(new char[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Fwd Eng {zoneinfo[1]}, Direction {zoneinfo[2]}, Used {zoneData[0]}, Total {zoneData[1]}");
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the output

Fwd Eng 1, Direction INPUT, Used 0, Total 2852

Answer (score 1):

To read all the lines from the file use [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx).

If the format is always the same, I would skip the header, using the Linq extension [Skip()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Linq.Enumerable.Skip%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).
Then split the fields on space with [this override of String.Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) that allow to filter out empty strings.

like:

```
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("yourfile.txt").Skip(4))
        {
            var fields = line.Split(new[] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            //do something with the fields
        }
```

In alternative if a tab separator is used, you could use: *line.Split('\t');*

Then you retrieve the field you need from the *fields* array, so for the 6th field:

```
var myField = fields[5]
```

You can put all the lines you have to write to a string array (or list), then write everything with [File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", myOutputLines);
```

---

**Complete solution**

Here is a possible solution that put all together using LINQ and IEnumerables, to streamline the file conversion without loading everything into memory (to allow to process efficiently large files)

```
var inputLines = File.ReadLines("yourfile.txt").Skip(4);
var outputHeader = new[] { "Region3 - Zoning", "Use/Total" };
var outputLines = inputLines.Select(line => line.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[5]);
File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", outputHeader.Concat(outputLines));
```